# DJI Cloud Sync?

Tags: ios, swift, synchronization, cloud, dji-sdk

I need a way to download flight logs from a DJI Users account using an iOS app I'm developing, I've noticed several other apps/websites allow a user to login into their DJI account and Sync their flight logs from DJI's servers, but I'm unable to find any reference or API's how they are managing to do this.

Ive tried searching through all documentation on the DJI developer portal but there nothing about that. Anyone have any idea how this is being done or know of any api to do this?

Examples of websites/app doing this are:

Drone Logbook:
https://blog.dronelogbook.com/?p=191

Kittyhawk
https://kittyhawk.io/dji-sync

AirData:
https://app.airdata.com/sync-app-ios

Comment: I don't think there is a public API for doing this. The services you cite probably have direct permission to integrate with DJI's cloud service. Your best bet might be to message DJI directly to request permission or instructions.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, yeah I've already emailed DJI waiting on their response... just thought I would ask here too in case someone knew.

Comment: Did they come back to you?

Comment: Not yet.... but it is DJI.

Comment: DJI say they don't allow any apps to do this, and they don't know the methods they're using & Flight Logs should only be available to the DJI support.

Comment: Joy... thank you.  That has blown my project out of the water.

Comment: Yeah not great,  you can try an unsupported method that the others are using but there's always a risk DJI close the loop hole at any time.

Comment: In that case they are most likely have included just a browser page and login directly to DJI. You could usually do this also by sending an HTTP request with right parameters. I do it for Google sheet and is possible for all website. You should then clean and get rid of the data you dont need and keep the rest.

Comment: Any ideas how to find out the URL to perform the request?

Comment: Any updates on this? I need the exact same feature in my app and I still don’t find any good practice to achieve this.

Comment: I'm afraid not.